# Listdefinitions use Listname as Contenttype

Tags: content-type, deployment, error, list-definition

I have a Sharepoint 2010 Foundation, VS2010 and
i use the Sharepointfactory(spsf.codeplex.com), if this is important.

My typical approach are:
I create first some fields, then i use these in a contenttype.
Then i create a Listdefinitions, that use this contenttype.
Most i use one Feature and one package with all this Elements.

If i create a List with my List definition in Sharepoint-Site, i get a List thats use the name of the list as Contenttype.
If create a new List with the Name "ABC", then i get a List with the Contenttype "ABC", that not exit. I can add my Contenttype manual, so my Contenttype is deploy, but not used.

Sometime after redeploy i haven't this Problem. I am working on two Sharepoint Projects at moment. A Big one with many Lists(incl. Fields, Contenttypes and Listdefininitons), and a smaller,  with only 2 Lists(incl. Field,CT,LD). 
My Problem occurs on  the big Project at the Dev-PC(at me and coworker) many time. This Project is i a early State, so i have test it only on the Dev-PCs.

The Smaller Project, this is my Solo-Project, run fine one my Dev-PC. I have make a Test-Deploy on a Stating-Server, work fine. But now i try to deploy it on the presentation/testing server from our Customer. And there i have the Problem again.

I have search here and on other site, but i don't found any solutions, because i didn't find any other Person with this Error.

I think, i have a knowledge gap or a Bug(Sharepoint/SPF/???).
Is this a familiar Problem or what is my mistake?

I am  very thankful for any hint.